# How to join 2 tables and group them by parent table id in laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, join

I have 2 tables:
t1: hotels
t2: people

There are 5 hotels and in every hotel a different number of people.
I'd like to get hotel name and people's names assigned to that hotel.
With the query I have it duplicated the hotel name as many times as there are people in it.

```
$hotels=DB::table('hotels')
->select('hotels.*','people.name')
->leftjoin('people','people.hotel_id','=','hotel.id')
->get();

return view('hotels', ['hotels' => $hotels]);
```

And in my view I have

```
@foreach($hotels as $h)
$h->hotel_name
@endforeach
```

hotel_name now shows up 4 times which is the same number of people assigned to the hotel_id.
I've tried using group_concat but with that I could only get the names of the people.

Is there a group by or some other method which could help me to get to my goal?

Comment: So... you want the Hotel name followed by an array of names assigned to that Hotel, am I right ?

Comment: Are you suggesting that you know how to do it in MySQL, but Laravel is getting in the way?

Comment: @Studio, can you mark one as correct so people know where to look?

Answer (score 3):

In your **HotelModel**

```
public function peoples()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\People','hotel_id');
}
```

In your **Controller** 
(use ->with('peoples') to solve the [n+1 problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-select-query-issue).

```
$hotels = Hotel::with('peoples')->get();    
return view('hotels', ['hotels' => $hotels]);
```

In your **View**

```
@foreach($hotels as $h)
    $h->hotel_name

    @foreach($h->peoples as $people)
        $people->name
    @endforeach

@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can achieve this using `group_concat` and `group_by` like so :

```
select hotels.* ,group_concat(people.name) as people_names
from hotels 
  left join people on hotels.id = people.hotel_id 
group by hotel_name;
```

using the query builder :

```
$hotels = DB::table('hotels')
   ->select('hotels.*', DB::raw('group_concat(people.name) as people_names'))
   ->leftjoin('people','people.hotel_id','=','hotels.id')
   ->groupBy('hotel_name')
   ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to your Hotel class

```
public function peoples()
{
    return $this->hasMany(People::class);
}
```

In your view:

```
@foreach ($hotel->people as $people)
    {{ $people->name }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Collection's `groupBy` function:

```
$hotels=DB::table('hotels')
->select('hotels.*','people.name')
->leftjoin('people','people.hotel_id','=','hotel.id')
->get();
$grouped = $hotels->groupBy('hotel_name');

return view('hotels', ['hotels' => $grouped]);
```

And then, print it like this:

```
@foreach($hotels as $key => $h)
    Hotel name: {{ $key }}
    @foreach ($h as $p)
        Person name: {{ $p }}
    @endforeach 
@endforeach
```

Comment: Hotel name: {{ $key }} displays nothing. Also in this case how can I get hotel_name, hotel_location and so on?

Comment: Using this, you will need to select them. Try to `dd($grouped);` to see how the information is organized. It will clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

Make a Hotel model and define the relationship:

```
public function people()
{
    return $this->hasMany(People::class);
}
```

I'm your controller:

```
$hotels = Hotel::all():
return view('hotels')->with('hotels', $hotels);
```

In your view:

```
@foreach($hotels as $hotel)

    {{ $hotel->name }}

    @foreach($hotel->people as $person)
        {{ $person->name }}
    @endforeach

@endforeach
```

Comment: I'm recommend you to read about [n-query problem](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading). Your example could propagate a bad habit.